# Simplest way to convert uploaded videos to mp4 before storing them on a server?

Tags: php, html, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I'm using a goDaddy server and cPanel to make a website, and I want to make a feature that lets users upload videos, save them on the server, then display them elsewhere on the site.

displaying uploaded videos:

`echo "<video controls><source src='{$video_row[$i]}'></video>";`

But I found out that most browsers can only play a few video formats like mp4. So I want to convert them all to mp4 before saving them to the server. So sometime before running the `move_uploaded_file()` function.

Is there something I can download and put on the server that will let me do that? From other questions I found about FFmpeg, but i couldn't figure out how to use it and if I can even install it on a godaddy server.

Php code:

```
if (isset($_FILES["submit_file"])) { //this comes from an html form
    $name = $_FILES['submit_file']['name'];
    $original_name = $name;
    $size = $_FILES['submit_file']['size'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['submit_file']['tmp_name'];
    $target_dir = null;

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); //get mime type
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $tmp_name);

    if ($mime == "video/mp4" || $mime == "video/wmv" || $mime == "video/avi" || $mime == "video/mov") {
        if ($mime != "video/mp4") {
            //CONVERT TO MP4
        }
        $target_dir = "uploads/videos/";
        $path = $target_dir.basename($name);

        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path) == true) {
            //moved
        }
    } else {
        //error: Unsupported File Type
    }
}
```

How do others deal with videos? I was able to upload and play mp4 videos fine with my method, but html5 can't seem to play other types, and I don't want to limit users to only upload mp4